# Slicing URL strings to to extract the a specific part

Tags: excel

I have an excel file with 8000 URLs in the following format:

```
mywebsite.com/product-cat-1/product-cat-2/product-name/
```

I would like to slice each URL string to be left with just the folders names:

```
/product-cat-1/product-cat-2/
```

Then remove the slashes

I have successfully stripped off the first part (`mywebsite.com`)

I am struggling with removing everything between the last two slashes ("/") including the final slash.

What should be the function ?

Comment: So, what would be output? `product-name`?

Answer (score 0):

Try following formula...

```
=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/", REPT(" ",100)),200))
```

[image]

Comment: The part I'm trying to extract and keep is /product-cat-1/product-cat-2/ now the last part, the last part I intend on using a wildcard to perform 301 redirects. Thanks for your input.

Comment: Can you please show us your sample data and expected output?

Comment: Both are in the original question. The first line is my example data, the second line is my expected output.